# OpenGL VBO / DisplayList in a game environment

Tags: performance, opengl, vbo, displaylist

I am working on a little game (using OS X Lion, Xcode 4, Objective-C / C++, Cocoa, OpenGL). It's a rather simple concept. I've got some objects that move around inside a two-dimensional array. Now i want to write an OpenGL GUI for my game.

What i did was go through my array and draw a cube for each object inside it, at its specific position, with a texture that depends on the kind of object. Of course my first naive implementation was a bit CPU-intensive, so the next step was to implement a texture atlas. Since i've got a lot of vertices, there is still a lot of room for improvement.

I read that VBOs and DisplayLists are a lot faster. I worked through some tutorials, but i've still got a lot of questions about the implementation in a real dynamic game environment.

Say i compile me some display lists for my game-objects. If i want to place it at a specific position i'd have to glTranslatef(). But a lot of glTranslatef() can be very CPU-intensive. How do i deal with that? Of course i could create a display list for each kind of game-object at every possible position, but it seems impractical, and it would only work because my game is tile-based...

VBOs seem to suffer from the same problem. Of course (at least from my understanding) i could create a whole mesh of vertices, then go through my array and for every object render a cube of vertices associated with the objects position. But i don't get how i'd apply a texture to a specific cube from a whole mesh of vertices. Do i have to create texture coordinates for every  cube face inside the mesh or would it be enough to create texture coordinate for all 6 faces of a cube?

Comment: "But a lot of glTranslatef() can be very CPU-intensive." So? You said that you're making "a little game". Do you have some reason to believe that a few matrix multiplies will bring down the performance of your game significantly? Unless you have hundreds of thousands of objects, it really doesn't matter. This question smells of premature optimizations. Don't get obsessed with "OMGFASTER!!!!11" Just get it working; you'd be surprised how often the obvious solution is fast enough.

Comment: Well, i've got levels around the size of 25*40 tiles, that's around 1000 objects. I'm drawing 1000 cubes / spheres doing 1000 glTranslatef()s. Activity Monitor is showing 20% CPU usage. With glTranslatef() commented out (i still draw all the objects, but all in one spot) CPU usage goes down to 12%. Seems significant to me. I haven't even implemented any effects and animations yet. Still using naive implementation of rendering objects right now, but using VBOs oder DisplayLists won't make glTranslatef() faster i guess.

Comment: Of course i could be totally wrong here, but i still wonder how bigger games deal with this stuff.

Comment: @cargath: Are those tiles moving in world space each frame, or are they stationary?

Comment: @genpfault: Some of my objects are animated, so i have to redraw the world each frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display lists and VBOs usually don't help with trivial geometry. Sometimes they can even slow it down if I recall correctly from the blue OpenGL book.

Display lists were "as good as it gets" in OpenGL 1.x but were considered legacy functionality with the introduction of VBOs.

It would help if we know what your OpenGL target version was. In OpenGL 1.x using Immediate mode what you do is set up your "camera matrix" ( OpenGL doesn't have one, you just leave its transpose on the matrix stack) then push and pop matricies for each model in your render loop.

Using OpenGL 2.x or 1.xARB extensions you can put your transforms in uniform matricies and then update the uniform for each model. This doesn't really buy you much since updating a uniform is also slow.

I think the best thing you could do would be to provide OpenGL with a (set of) attributes matricies in the shader. This would reduce your CPU overhead by transferring all the data in one go. I can't think of the technical implementation details, but I think attributes are per vertex so you would have to pass an index of where to look in the other buffer you used to put the transforms. I have never done this since most models contain more geometry and texture information than the time to set up transforms.

That being said, redesigning it with VBOs and supplying the transforms in attributes is probably a great deal of work for 8% CPU usage gains. 8% on one core of probably a 2.0ghz core 2 duo

EDIT

Uniform buffer object is what I really wanted. Probably for a uniform block layout. The Blue book (and maybe Orange book) and google have more details.

Comment: Well, of course at this point there is no actual need for improvements, but as i said, i plan on implementing some effects and animations. I'm still in an early stage of development, so optimization might become necessary, and i guess i'd be easier to use the best technique from the beginning than rewrite everything once i realize naive implementation is to slow. Also 8% CPU usage might not be a lot, but it's almost half the total CPU usage.

Comment: Target OpenGL 3.3 / 4.2. Don't use immediate mode or the matrix functions of GL1. I suggest Siftless tutorials to get started. Using shaders that declare the matricies in unforms that are populated by a uniform buffer I believe is the most efficient way.

Comment: I've used OpenGL before, but only for hardware accelerated 2D stuff. It's the first time i create something 3D, so even if i might not need to use all the fancy techniques for this game, i'm still interested in implementing them for learning purposes. 20% of CPU usage seems like a lot for such a small game, there are games with characters whose faces consist of more polygons than my entire game world. I might have a thousand cube, but games like Serious Sam deal with hundreds of enemys. I'm really interested in how this works.

Comment: I really don't know which version i use. Is there a way to find out? I'm using the libraries that come with Xcode 4 on OS X Lion. Some of the headers suggest 1.2, some others suggest 3.x.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will look into them this weekend, as soon as i have some spare time :)

Comment: Using GLEW you can query what versions of OpenGL your host supports. Alternatively if it supports ARB extensions to older OpenGL versions that give you the functionality you need. E.G. Shaders in openGL 1.x via ARB extensions.